# Convert a list into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a function that takes as an argument a list and must return the elements of the list into an array.
For example in case of the input:

```
{value: 1, rest: {value: 2, rest: null}}
```

The output should looke like:

```
[1, 2]
```

This is how I tried to solve it:

```
function listToArray(list){
  var arr = [];
    for (var node = list; node; node = node.rest) {
        arr.unshift(node);

    }
  return arr;

}
console.log(listToArray({value: 1, rest: {value: 2, rest: null}}));
```

And the output I get is:

```
[{value: 2, rest: null}, {
value:  1
rest:   {value: 2, rest: null}
}]
```

Does anyone know what should I change to make it work?

Comment: using `arr.push(node);` instead of `arr.unshift(node);` will change the order of the elements, but still the output format is not the wanted one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were just missing the `.value` from node.

```js
function listToArray(list){
  var arr = [];
    for (var node = list; node; node = node.rest) {
        arr.unshift(node.value);

    }
  return arr;

}
console.log(listToArray({value: 1, rest: {value: 2, rest: null}}));
```

Note you might want `push` instead of `unshift`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion to grab all the inner object values.

```js
var obj = {value: 1, rest: {value: 2, rest: null}};
var list = objToList(obj, 'value', 'rest');

console.log(list);

function objToList(obj, valueField, targetField) {
  return objToListInner(obj, valueField, targetField, []);
}

function objToListInner(obj, valueField, targetField, list) {
  if (isObject(obj)) {
    list.push(obj[valueField]);
    objToListInner(obj[targetField], valueField, targetField, list)
  }
  return list;
}

function isObject(obj) {
  return obj !== null && typeof obj === 'object';
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  top: 0;
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

---

A bit of code golf. ;)

```js
let obj  = {value: 1, rest: {value: 2, rest: null}},
    list = objToList(obj, 'value', 'rest');

console.log(list);

function objToList(o, v, t, l) {
  return o ? objToList(o[t], v, t, (l||[]).concat(o[v])) : (l||[])
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  top: 0;
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```